# MacBook forgetting display arrangement

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

My Mac seems to be forgetting display arrangements for external monitors. It doesn't matter what type of connector it is (Tried Apple converter to VGA as well as non-apple to DVI). Within only a few hours after unplugging the display it will be reset.

Has anyone seen anything about similar issues? Is it maybe Mavericks-related?

Comment: It sounds like it could be a problem with permissions, check out my answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117038/2313  Even though it is a different problem, it is probably the same solution.

Comment: Nope, didn't help :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist` as well as all files in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost` which began with `com.apple.windowserver` seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem but it persists even after deleting these files, restarting, etc. :(

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't quite figure out what got it but I thought it was this. Could have been this or a bunch of other things.

Comment: I've seen others report that the fix you provided worked for them as well, must be something different in my setup.

Comment: This is happening to me on Catalina as well. Trying this now, hopefully it fixes the problem!

Answer (score 3):

### As of 2022 the only thing that worked for me is `displayplacer` tool

https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer

Disclaimer: I am not the creator and I am not related to this tool

### Tutorial

```sh
brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn
brew install displayplacer
displayplacer list

# copy the last command, it is going to be similar to this
displayplacer "id:18173D22-3EC6-E735-EEB4-B003BF681F30+F466F621-B5FA-04A0-0800-CFA6C258DECD res:1440x900 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0" "id:4C405A05-8798-553B-3550-F93E7A7722BB res:768x1360 hz:60 color_depth:8 scaling:off origin:(1440,0) degree:90" "id:A46D2F5E-487B-CC69-C588-ECFD519016E5 mode:3 origin:(-1440,0) degree:270"
```

Now that you have this command you can run it as a shortcut (`Shortcuts` app from Apple) and stop wasting so much time configuring screens

### Tutorial `Shorcuts` app

- Open `Shorcuts` built-in app
- Create a new shortcut
  [image]

[image]

```sh
# source lines are needed to add programs to path in shorcuts terminal
source ~/.zprofile
source ~/.zshrc

displayplacer "id:18173D22-3EC6-E735-EEB4-B003BF681F30+F466F621-B5FA-04A0-0800-CFA6C258DECD res:1440x900 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0" "id:4C405A05-8798-553B-3550-F93E7A7722BB res:768x1360 hz:60 color_depth:8 scaling:off origin:(1440,0) degree:90" "id:A46D2F5E-487B-CC69-C588-ECFD519016E5 mode:3 origin:(-1440,0) degree:270"
```

- Add a keyboard shortcut and add it to menu bar if wanted

[image]