# MBP resets display arrangement on restart

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mojave, preferences

I am running 10.14.1 Mojave on a mid-2015 MBP, connected to an external monitor. Every time the machine is restarted my display arrangement is reset. This only happens on 10.14.1 and did not happen before.

I deleted `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist` per [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117581/macbook-air-forgetting-display-arrangement) but to no avail.

[image: Machine info]

Comment: is that only for one user or for other user as well

Comment: @Buscar웃 I only have one user

Comment: the make new user and try it, this is to eliminate some app you have doing that, and to find out if your user permissions need repair.

Comment: Going to mark this as resolved; there seem to be no issues at the moment. I am guessing it was related to an application.